# Cannot insert explicit value. INSERT OFF

Tags: c#, database, sql-server-2008, uniqueidentifier

I have created a database in SQL Server 2008 with an identity column that is incrementing by 1.

Now in C# I'm getting an error like the title when I'm restoring a data in table.

I sent the data from table1 (including the column with identity) to archives and now when I'm restoring the data (including the column with identity) from archives to table1 I'm getting the error.

This is the code

```
private void btnRestoreSupp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    crud.AddRecord("Insert into Supplier (SupplierID, CompanyName, SupplierName, ContactNo, EmailAddress, Description) values ('" + txtSupplierIDarc.Text + "','" + txtCompanyArc.Text + "','" + txtSupplierNArc.Text + "','" + txtContactNoArc.Text + "','" + txtEmailArc.Text + "','" + txtSupDesArc.Text + "')");
}
```

Now I read a tutorial and add `IDENTITY_INSERT` to my code. now it didn't get error but inserting a blank data to table. This is my code

```
private void btnRestoreSupp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    crud.AddRecord("SET IDENTITY_INSERT Supplier ON Insert into Supplier (SupplierID, CompanyName, SupplierName, ContactNo, EmailAddress, Description) values ('" + txtSupplierIDarc.Text + "','" + txtCompanyArc.Text + "','" + txtSupplierNArc.Text + "','" + txtContactNoArc.Text + "','" + txtEmailArc.Text + "','" + txtSupDesArc.Text + "')Set IDENTITY_INSERT Supplier OFF");
}
```

PS I know I didn't use parameters. I'll change it afterwards.

Comment: Is it inserting blank data in all the columns?

Comment: no sir, im planning to restore the old deleted values. for example. i delete this data: productID(identity),productname from table1 and sent it to table2. now im restoring the data productID,productname from table2 back to table1.

Comment: I got what you are trying to achieve. SupplierId column in table1 is not-null INT column? If it is not-null then it should throw exception and should not insert a row at all. Did you check in AddRecord method that any exception thrown?

Comment: Try adding `;` between your sql statements: `SET IDENTITY_INSERT Supplier ON; Insert into Supplier (SupplierID, CompanyName, SupplierName, ContactNo, EmailAddress, Description) values ('" + txtSupplierIDarc.Text + "','" + txtCompanyArc.Text + "','" + txtSupplierNArc.Text + "','" + txtContactNoArc.Text + "','" + txtEmailArc.Text + "','" + txtSupDesArc.Text + "'); Set IDENTITY_INSERT Supplier OFF'`